# Puppeteer: compare return result with a text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So I have this code, which is now scraping the web and returns the result (message and username):

```
function containsWords(words, message) {
    return words.some(w => message.includes(w));
}

async function grabResult(page) {
    const message = await page.$eval(
        'div > div:nth-child(2)',
        (el) => el.innerText
    );
    
    const username = await page.$eval(
        'child(15) .username',
        (el) => el.innerText
    );

    return {
        message: containsWords(['http', 'https'], message) ? '' : message,
        username: username
    };
};


module.exports = grabResult;
```

Since the above code is scraping a website that is dynamically changing, what I'm trying to achieve is to avoid returning duplicate messages.

One of the ways I thought it could be possible done is by:

creating a .txt file, in which would be stored the previous result.

So, anytime a fresh data is retrieved, before return, it would compare the new 'message' result with the .txt 'message' result, and if it's the same data, it would return an empty message:

```
{ message: '', username: 'John' }
```

If the message data is unique however, it would return the data as it normally would:

```
{ message: 'message text', username: 'John' }
```

And update the .txt file with that data (so that it could compare with the freshly data again next time).

So basically, using a .txt file for comparison, before returning (logging) the data in the terminal.

My question is: is this process even possible?

If yes, any clues or help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not a coder, I hope I made it clear.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to use [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) instead of plain text — it would make all the checking easier.

1. Create a file `data.json` in the same folder as your script placed in. The file must contain just two curly brackets: `[]`. It will designate an empty object for starters.
2. Your script will read the file using [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module and will make a JS array from it. Then it will check if the array has the current message. If so, the message will be converted to an empty string. If not, the array will be updated and the file will be rewritten.

Here is a script example:

```js
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs');

function containsWords(words, message) {
    return words.some(w => message.includes(w));
}

async function grabResult(page) {
    const username = await page.$eval(
        'child(15) .username',
        (el) => el.innerText
    );

    let message = await page.$eval(
        'div > div:nth-child(2)',
        (el) => el.innerText
    );

    if(containsWords(['http', 'https'], message)) message = '';

    const dataArray = JSON.parse(readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf8'));

    if (dataArray.includes(message)) {
      message = '';
    } else {
      dataArray.push(message);
      writeFileSync('./data.json', JSON.stringify(dataArray));
    }

    return { message, username };
};

module.exports = grabResult;
```

Comment: hey vsemozhebuty again:) I have tried running the script, but getting an error: ```dataObject[username] ??= [];
                           ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='``` . Would be awesome if we could sort this one out, been struggling for a month now with this...

Comment: Maybe this will help. Full error screenshot: https://ibb.co/H72WVst

Comment: It is a bit new syntax: [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). It needs [Node.js 15.14.0 or more](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment). Can you upgrade your Node.js? The last version recently released is [16](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/). If you cannot, I will try to use an older syntax.

Comment: Yes, I'm using an older version of Node (14.16.1 LTS). I'm afraid of upgrading, because I don't want for the script to stop working.. It was built for older version. Would be great if you could update with an older syntax... thanks!

Comment: IT WORKED! WOOhoo! thanks man, you saved me again :) appreciate it very much! Have a wonderful Sunday! thanks again!

Comment: @robert0 Thanx) Good luck with all the projects)

Comment: vsemozhebuty, very quick question. Right now when the same message is posted by a different username, it goes through... Is it possible so that it would only look at the message and if the message is duplicate, it won't post, regardless of the username?

Comment: @robert0 It is even simpler. Recreate the JSON file, but instead of `{}`, put `[]` in it (it will mean an empty array). I've updated the code.